# Display 10 array cards

Tags: php, html

http://plnkr.co/edit/06lu6r34eGNfRq1fygNy

I want to only display 10 "cards" from my array, how would I do so?
I tried using `unset()` but it is very inefficient and doesn't even work for multiple cards.
Also how can I make the code display the "cards" horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: "it is very inefficient" --- what does it mean?

Comment: Is your code so long that it won't fit in the question? If so please at least show a relevant extract.

Comment: @zerkms I have to make many lines of unused code, it takes up bandwith etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn I thought it would be neater to upload it to Plunker..next time I won't I guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’d like to use `unset`, the correct syntax would be `unset($cards[1]); unset($cards[2]); unset($cards[3]); ...` and so on.

However, for your particular situation, I’ll recommend you to use `array_slice`:

```
$cards = array(
    "Messi",           "Ronaldo",         "Ibrahimovic",     "Ribery",          "Robben",          "Neymar",          "Rooney",          "Casillas",
    "Falcao",          "Van Persie",      "Hazard",          "Iniesta",         "Xavi",            "Schweinsteiger",  "Silva",           "Fabregas",
    "Lahm",            "Aguero",          "Cavani",          "Vidic",           "Ozil",            "Mata",            "Bale",            "ThiagoSilva",
    "Kompany",         "Tevez",           "Toure",           "Ramos",           "Suarez",          "Pirlo",           "DiMaria",         "Neuer",
    "Pique",           "Buffon",          "Lewandowski",     "Gomez",           "Chiellini",       "Cole",            "Pedro",           "Busquets",
    "Cech",            "Muller",          "Hummels",         "Alonso",          "Navas",           "Modric",          "Cazorla",         "Gotze",
    "Benzema",         "Vidal",           "Lavezzi"
);
shuffle($cards);
$cards = array_slice($cards, 0, 10);
```

For the horizontal display, you may simply omit the `<br>` at the end of every iteration of your loop, but, depending on the resolution of the user’s browser, the images may occupy more than one line. For a strictly horizontal arrangement, use an HTML table with 10 columns:

```
print("<table><tr>");
foreach($cards as $card){
$img = "http://d2bm3ljpacyxu8.cloudfront.net/fit/105x97/http://clearpkz.webs.com/webstore/".$card.".png";
print("<td><img src=\"".$img."\"/></td>");
}
print("</tr></table>");
```

Comment: accepting answer will help others to find the best solution.

Comment: @kumar_v I cannot accept an answer until 10 minutes after the question was posted.

Answer (score 1):

The following works too:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  echo $cards[$i] ." <br>"; // put the name above the card
  echo "<img src='http://d2bm3ljpacyxu8.cloudfront.net/fit/105x97/http://clearpkz.webs.com/webstore/$card.png'> <br>";

  }
```

If you want them horizontally, and without names, don't put in the `<br>`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  echo "<img src='http://d2bm3ljpacyxu8.cloudfront.net/fit/105x97/http://clearpkz.webs.com/webstore/$card.png'>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will use Sharanya Dutta's code for slicing, and your code for making the images horizontal. Thanks very much. :)

Comment: @Journey - sounds like a good plan!